# Testing for cakeError() being thrown

Tags: testing, cakephp, error-handling, simpletest

I am using Unit Testing in CakePHP 1.3. My app uses a very simple ErrorHandler as [taught by the book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1188/Error-Handling). One of my models calls `$this->cakeError('myError')` if something is wrong.

Now I want a test case for my model, that checks if - wrong data given - the error handler is properly called.

SimpleTest offers [`expectError()`](http://simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/UnitTester/UnitTestCase.html#expectError) but this seems to be made for standard PHP errors. CakePHP's error handling is a different thing, though, these errors are not caught by expectError(). If cakeError() is called in a test, the error message is rendered, rather than the test results.

How can I test for expected cakeErrors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use a partial mock and mock the `cakeError` method. Then you can use `expectOnce` to assert the `cakeError` method is called. See the [documentation](http://simpletest.org/en/partial_mocks_documentation.html) for an example and further explanations.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the way to go. Never came across mocks before, though. After I have created the Mock AppError class, do you know where I need to create an instance of it, so Cake actually uses it instead of the original one?

Comment: I wouldn't mock the AppError class because you can't replace the original instance easily. Instead I would mock the cakeError() method of your model.

Comment: Of course, great, that'll do the trick. Would you mind updating your answer, adding this specific bit of information?

Comment: If you're looking for a full example of this with code, go here: http://blog.deversus.com/2014/12/cakephp-1-3-simpletest-and-partial-mocks/.